# Djstripe - Stripe webhook 404 error: how to resolve?

Tags: django, heroku, stripe-payments

For my Django project, I am using djstripe. Using test data, I have confirmed that payments are successful. However, when testing a webhook, I get errors of 404 and then it sometimes changes to 503 (for the same webhook). I am using Heroku free tier so I am not sure if that is the problem, or if I am configuring the webhooks entirely wrong (likely since this is my first project). Any help is appreciated.

Stripe endpoint I have as [heroku domain]/users/accounts/webhook/ and my project urls is `path('users/accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),`

[image: Error 404]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

404 means that the URL you've provided to Stripe for your webhook is not found on/by your server; this is something you'll need to investigate on your end.

If you share more code - like specifically the code containing your route for the webhook - that might be useful for helping you diagnose the issue here.

Comment: You're welcome.  I have absolutely done that a non-zero number of times.

Answer (score 0):

i have found some solutions.
1- copy response of HTML tags and convert it to an HTML Page. you will be able to see the error raising from your platform which is failing the webhook.
2- Debug the each line of webhook view/code.